# Work around for maximum argument length when linking on win32

Tags: mingw, cmake

I've run into a bug on windows CMake/MinGW builds where the number of object files sent to the linker causes the arguments list to exceed the maximum 32k characters the windows API allows. This manifests itself as an amazingly unhelpful "Error running link command: The parameter is incorrect" error.

Has anyone run into this before and found a workaround that *doesn't involve reorganising the project paths or spliting it into libraries* (as both are a lot of extra work)?

For example I know ld.exe takes a @file parameter to pass arguments, but can mingw-make be told to use this when arguments get too long?

Does running under msys / sh.exe work around this this limit?

Comment: It would help to know which CMake generator you're using. MinGW makefiles? MSYS makefiles? nmake makefiles?

Comment: Instead of telling mingw-make to use @response files when the arguments get too long, why not just use them all of the time and save the hassle?

Comment: @Jack: MingGW makefiles, but it also failed for codeblocks project (also MinGW based). I don't think this project builds on msys but i'll test. @Reinderien: because then on smaller links it's hard to debug linker errors (as the command wouldn't show the files/args under make VERBOSE=1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I read [this bug report](http://www.cmake.org/Bug/bug_view_page.php?bug_id=10401&history=1) correctly, it's a known problem and has been fixed. I'm not sure if the product version field refers to the version exhibiting the bug or the version fixing the bug.

Comment: This bug was fixed in CMake 2.8.2

Comment: Ah, well that makes things easy then (I'm currently using 2.6).